# Floating button doesn't seen because of Bottom Nav

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, navigation

On Main activity XML I have one buttom nav and on another fragment I have a floating button. This button is not visible because of the buttom nav. If I add on floating buttom this line -> android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" instead of android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" it works fine but I think it is not best practice. How can I show the button?

MainActivity XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_buttom_navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_buttom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Floating button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.listEvent.ListEventFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_timeliner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make more sense to make the fragment height 0dp.

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />
```

Comment: how is this different compared to what OP has ? just the constraint ?

Comment: app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

Comment: Okey but how I can reach to id of bottomNavigationView? Floating button and bottomNavigationView are in different XMLs.

Comment: you can't reach then you need to increase the size

Comment: i thought they were in the same xml

Comment: give me some time i did some research

Comment: Yes sure, I am checking too.

Comment: are you there i found

Comment: can you just share me the main activity page

Comment: No I couldnt, I added main acitivity.

Comment: i edited can you try my code again

Comment: this will work for you. If I was able to help, can you give a +1 vote and click the tick?

Answer (score 0):

You should change this in `<fragment>`

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
```

the reason is that the fragment is now underneath the BottomNavigationView while you want it to be on top of it

Comment: I think it makes more sense to set the fragment height to 0 dp in the mainactivity page.

Comment: or if it uses FrameLayout, I think it would be more reasonable to make its height 0dp.

Comment: I added main activity xml's codes.

Comment: @FunniestAnimalVideos yes, exactly like i suspected. see my edit for the fix

Comment: @id/bottomNavigationView is not a sibling in the same ConstraintLayout

Comment: @FunniestAnimalVideos yes it is. You literally showed me the complete main xml. In there is a `<fragment>` . I'm talking about that one

Comment: I added the fragment.